# How to specify 32 bit and 64 executable in Info.plist

Tags: macos

How to specify two different executable in Info.plist depending on architecture . I want to given  both 32 and 64 bit binary in my plugin.

how to  tell info.plist to load respective bit binary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't specify multiple executables.

Instead, you can pack the 32 and 64 bit executable inside a "universal" (multi-architecture) binary using *lipo*.

```
$ lipo -info /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari 
Architectures in the fat file: /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari are: x86_64 i386
```